# Issue downloading dependency from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am currently trying to download a dependency from an Amazon S3 bucket for a maven framework project but Intellij is unable to download when I compile. In the .m2 repository it shows the folder for the dependency, it just doesn't contain the required information. There is also a settings file in the .m2 providing a username and password to the S3. In the Intellij console all dependencies are underlined in red in the maven window but only the two dependencies relying on the S3 are not being imported. Also, when I install the locally they are found and work fine.

Some of the actions I have taken:

- Deletion of the repository
- Deletion of the .m2 folder
- Invalidate and cache
- Reloading all projects
- Downloading sources and documentation
- Rebuilding
- Installing locally (as mentioned above)
- Reinstalling Intellij
- Deleting the project and re-loading from code commit

If anyone has any ideas then I would be very grateful to try them out!

Comment: Do you have aws-maven extension configured in the project? Is it public/private bucket? Do you have AWS credentials configured in settings.xml, or ~/.aws/credentials?
See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135229

Comment: The current maven extension is:         <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

Comment: The AWS credentials or in settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the proper Maven dependencies in the POM file that is located in the AWS Example Github located here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3

This POM file is valid within an INtelliJ project:

[image]